# Ratio of total squares to empty squares on dart game tending to the number e

Tags: probability

[Finding e by throwing darts on a post by Mike Lawler](https://mikesmathpage.wordpress.com/) makes reference to the following quote on [John Allen Paulos *A Numerate Life*](http://johnallenpaulos.com/a_numerate_life.html):

[image]

I looked up a similar exercise on the first link solved by [N.Taleb](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/ProbabilityQuizDuJour2.shtml), regarding the probability of leaving half of the checkerboard empty of darts, and it involves compositions, as well as the multinomial distribution with equal probabilities. He solves it with Mathematica - so I guess numerically.

In the case of the number e, I guess there has to be a close formula, like a limit explaining this. A law of sorts, but which one? How is this proven?

Comment: Poisson distribution?

Comment: The key is that we have a binomial distribution for the number of pennys on each square. If $n$ is large and $p$ is small, we can approximate this very good with a poisson-distribution with parameter $np$. In the given case, we have $np=1$, so we have approximately a poisson-distribution with parameter $1$, hence $P(X=0)\approx P(X=1)\approx\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: The problem is that the distribution of the number of pennies on each square is not independent. For instance, if $X_n$ is the number of pennies on the nth square, then $0 = \mathbb{P}(X_1=1 \mid X_2=64) \neq \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1)$, so how can we apply either a binomial or Poisson distribution?

Comment: But the choices of squares is independent and the probability for having no penny is equal for every square.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419736/ Here, for each single square, we have n=64 attempts which will hit with probability 1/64. The probability of no hit is roughly 1/e. (In the linked question and answers, they compute the complementary probability to be 1-1/e.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of squares and $U$ the number of squares having no penny. We draw $N$ random numbers from $1$ to $N$.

For each square, the probability that this specific square has no penny, is $(\frac{N-1}{N})^N$ , which is approximately $\frac{1}{e}$, if $N$ is large.

Now set $X_j=1$ , if $j$ has no penny and $X_j=0$ otherwise. Then, the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_N$ is the number of squares with no pennys.

Since $E(X_1)=\cdots=E(X_n)\approx\frac{1}{e}$ and the expectations add, we have $E(U)\approx N\cdot \frac{1}{e}=\frac{N}{e}$

Comment: The number of squares with exactly one penny is also approximately $\large \frac{N}{e}$, if $N$ is large.

Comment: Isn't the question asking for $E\left(\frac{N}{U}\right) = e$, which is different to $\frac{N}{E(U)}$ (by, eg, Jensen)?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. But since we can expect $U\approx \frac{N}{e}$, we will get $\frac{N}{U}\approx e$. Of course, it is not predictible which value $U$ will have, and we have to consider the standard deviation of $U$. If $N$ is very large, we have a rather small standard deviation compared to the expectation, so we will get a reasonable approximation.